# Send print commands directly to LPT parallel port using C#.net

Tags: c#, printing, lpt

As in DOS we can do:

```
ECHO MESSAGE>LPT1
```

How can we achieve same thing in C# .NET?

Sending information to COM1 seems to be easy using C# .NET.

What about LPT1 ports?

I want to send Escape commands to the thermal printer.

Answer (score 4):

In C# 4.0 and later its possible, first you need to connect to that port using the `CreateFile` method then open a filestream to that port to finally write to it.
Here is a sample class that writes two lines to the printer on `LPT1`.

```
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace YourNamespace
{
    public static class Print2LPT
        {
            [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
            static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile(string lpFileName, FileAccess dwDesiredAccess,uint dwShareMode, IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes, FileMode dwCreationDisposition, uint dwFlagsAndAttributes, IntPtr hTemplateFile);

            public static bool Print()
            {
                string nl = Convert.ToChar(13).ToString() + Convert.ToChar(10).ToString();
                bool IsConnected= false;

                string sampleText ="Hello World!" + nl +
                "Enjoy Printing...";     
                try
                {
                    Byte[] buffer = new byte[sampleText.Length];
                    buffer = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sampleText);

                    SafeFileHandle fh = CreateFile("LPT1:", FileAccess.Write, 0, IntPtr.Zero, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
                    if (!fh.IsInvalid)
                    {
                        IsConnected= true;                    
                        FileStream lpt1 = new FileStream(fh,FileAccess.ReadWrite);
                        lpt1.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        lpt1.Close();
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    string message = ex.Message;
                }

                return IsConnected;
            }
        }
}
```

Assuming your printer is connected on the `LPT1` port, if not you will need to adjust the `CreateFile` method to match the port you are using.

you can call the method anywhere in your program with the following line

```
Print2LPT.Print();
```

I think this is the shortest and most efficient solution to your problem.